# How to add a menu item to menu bar in vs 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I need to add sql and table menu to menu bar in visual studio 2013 .
But I can't do it .

When I tap to tool > costomaize > and go to command tab and select menu bar there are "table" and "sql" menu both there but can't active them to menu bar . how can I costomiz them to be in menu bar ?

Please help me how can I add them to my menu bar like as vs 2012 ?